# How can I rent a car one way from the US to Mexico?

Tags: usa, automobiles, mexico, rental, one-way

I am moving from Asheville, North Carolina, to Puerto Vallarta, Mexico later this year.  We have two dogs that are too large for an airplane.

We need to rent a car to drive to Puerto Vallarta and then drop the rental car off in Puerto Vallarta without making the return round trip.

Is there a car rental company in America that will allow us to drive to our destination and drop the car there?
Alternatively, is there a border crossing where we could cross the border and rent a car from a Mexican car rental company and then drop off the American car in Texas?

Comment: Which ones have you checked? Most will, but require additional Mexican Liability Insurance, and limit which types of vehicles can be taken. This [article is useful](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/can-drive-rental-car-mexico-110940.html).

Comment: I suspect a one way can rental from the USA to Mexico is going to be impossible.

Comment: @gerrit agreed, might be difficult. Enterprise might, as it has locations in Mexico. Better to do as OP suggests, cross in Texas or, better, Tijuana and walk across.

Comment: Yes, you can rent a car not a problem. Make sure you must have the following requirement: 1, valid US driving licence 2, Insurance for your entire journey 3, valid credit card with sufficient balance available There are many rental car companies offering to rent, just Google and you will be able to find one

Comment: Why can't I upvote this question?

Comment: @Mickeymouse: the OP is asking for a very specific car rental type (one way to Mexico), which your answer does not address at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to, but it would probably be difficult, cost prohibitive, if not impossible.  I would suggest renting one car for the US leg of the journey(eg Ashville to San Diego), then crossing the border either on foot or by public transport, then renting another car on the Mexico side (eg Tijuana to Puerto Vallarta).  I don't know if there are any overland pet transport companies, but you may look into that as well.